# ¿se puede hacer un condición sin if?

Tags: java, condiciones

queremos hacer una funcion que, si la suma de dos variables es positiva el sistema me devuelve el valor de la suma, en el caso de que fuera negativa me tendria que dar un 0, esto sin utilizar la funcion if.

Comment: Pues usa un switch.

Comment: al final de la función `return ( (a+b) >= 0 );`

Comment: Hola @DanielgarciaGonzales , Bienvenido a [StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), te recomiendo un [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por la pagina para poder ganar tu primera medalla, y ver [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para hacer un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y la comunidad acepte de buena forma tu pregunta ya que este no es un lugar donde resuelvan tu tarea.

Answer (score 1):

Esta sería la función:

```
public int funcion(int a,int b){
    return (a+b>0?a+b:0);
}
```

El operador condicional ternario en java '?' el signo de interrogacion te permite evaluar una expresion logica colocada justo antes de este operador , de cumplirse la condicion de ser cierta el resultado seria la expresion colocada justo despues de este simbolo, se pone despues los dos puntos ':' para separarla de la siguiente expresion que seria el resultado de que la condicion fuese falsa, del modo :

expresionC ? expresionV : expresionF

donde:

expresionC seria la expresion a evaluar
expresionV sera la expresion resultante de que expresionC sea verdadera
exprecionF de ser falsa

ten en cuenta que expresionV y F son 'expresiones', aunq pueden ser valores constantes. ej:

(a>b)?1:0  donde recibiriamos un 1 si la variable a es mayor que b o 0 de ser menor o igual

Comment: Alexmaister, te recomiendo que agregues algún tipo de explicación al código. En [es.so] se busca una mínima calidad en las preguntas y respuestas, no es recomendable pegar un código sin más explicaciones, lo más normal es que sea reportada por baja calidad como en este caso. Dada la simpleza del código, bastaría con que explicaras un poco que es el operador ternario y como funciona en este caso. Un saludo.

Comment: Vale gracias , ya edite la respuesta

Comment: aunque no estés usando directamente un if, las condicionales ternaria son un short Hand de la misma... realmente estás utilizando una máscara de un if.